# Error in triggering jenkins job from Slack

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

I am integrating Jenkins in Slack to facilitate build from Slack.

I configured the `Build Trigger` section of my job

[image]

Then I added `Slash Commands` to slack and configured it as below.

[image]

Now, I went to slack and typed `/dev-backend`, and it is throwing the error,

`/dev-backend failed with the error "invalid_url"`

I tried hitting the URL directly from `postman` which is giving the `Authentication required` response.

How can I add the authentication so that I can trigger build from slack? I thought the token provided in the build triggers section of Jenkins was enough.

Comment: @stud3nt It did not work

Comment: Yes. I got the token from Admin account itself

Comment: I tried in curl, `curl -X POST -u "<user-name>" "http://192.168.**.**:8080/job/*******-build-DEV-Backend/build?token=6081437*********437572"` triggered the build. This means the setup is working, but How to convert that curl url into a url for `slash-commands` of slack?

Comment: Try with `http://<user-name>:<token>@192.168.**.**:8080/job/*******-build-DEV-Backend/build?token=<token>` and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @stud3nt It worked when I hit the URL through postman. Same change I did in `slash-commands` configuration. But, still unable to trigger the build from Slack

Comment: Nope, it's in an external server

Comment: I will check that. Although, if the request is sent from postman successfully, shouldn't it also work from Slack?

Comment: The port is 8080

Comment: The port will not allow connection from outside our oganisation network. But, I am connected to our organisation network and using Slack. I don't think that is the problem here

Comment: I agree, port shouldn't be a problem. But I believe for slack to work, the jenkins url should be accessible from outside your network. As slack does not belong to your organisation network.

Comment: I tried giving anonymous user read permission and ended up with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823858/jenkins-not-letting-me-to-login. This is really serious issue

Comment: is the slash command working with jenkins csrf security protection off?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kind of outdated question but I was also struggling with this error, so maybe it will help someone in the future. If you are getting `/command failed with the error "invalid_url"` and you are able to hit your application endpoint via eg. Bash shell:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer your-bearer-token' -H 'Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8' --data '{"channel":"#test","text":"Hello, Slack!"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/your/application/endpoint
```

it means that Slack can't access/see the URL that you passed in Slack API Applications Settings.

In my case the problem was that I was passing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/endpoint` in Slash Commands configuration which was visible only by my computer. The easiest way to make it visible for Slack is to use `ngrok`.

So if you are getting this error the steps are as follows:

1. Install `ngrok`
2. Run your app on localhost, eg. `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
3. In Bash shell type `ngrok http 8000`
4. Copy url returned by `ngrok`, in my case `http://c609-91-234-49-229.ngrok.io`
5. Paste copied URL to Slack Slash Commands configuration instead of localhost.